# Using Configuration manager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, appsettings

Looking at an example where the server receives a file on the streamReader from the client.

```
string key = "UploadSalesFileToServer";
            GetValue(key);
```

is added to the function, which uses:

```
private static string GetValue(string name)
        {
            var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Modules/Work/web.config");
            var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            string configValue = configuration.AppSettings.Settings[name].Value;

            return configValue;
        }
```

and in web.config I use:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="UploadSalesFileToServer"
         value="1111-fasad-32233-ffdsff"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Can anyone tell me what happens here through out? the app settings is used to check the correct file is being received?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Does everything work and you aren't sure why/how it works?

Comment: im not sure what it is meant to do? but it doesnt throw any errors?

Answer (score 0):

GetValue trying to read config value from configuration file which is not exactly application configuration and situated in different directory under relative path "~/Modules/Work/web.config"

Comment: yeah it reads app settings and returns they value, but what is the point of this? what is it used for?...something to do with, passing a file back to the server, and using the app settings to see where it is store?

Comment: In general configuration files is a place to store settings for application. You can get it values through run time as you can change it without rebuild application. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But seems your question is about something different and depend on code which you haven't show. No one like read tea leaves. No one like   abstract question.